# How to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux

Good evening,

i am quite new to react and i am building my first major project. I want to do the following thing:
I want to change the value of the items state when the user selects the specific size of the product. When the user selects the size, products with only that size should appear on the screen.
The last thing i should do is setting the state when the user changes the size, but i cant manage to do that:

my code:

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { listProduct } from '../../actions/productActions'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Filter = () => {
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)
  const { products } = productList
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [items, setItem] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProduct())
    setItem(products)
  }, [])

  console.log(items)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === 'S') {
      return console.log(products.filter((item) => item.size === 'S'))
    } else if (e.target.value === 'XS') {
      return console.log(products.filter((item) => item.size === 'XS'))
    } else if (e.target.value === 'M') {
      return console.log(products.filter((item) => item.size === 'M'))
    } else if (e.target.value === 'L') {
      return console.log(products.filter((item) => item.size === 'L'))
    } else if (e.target.value === 'XL') {
      return console.log(products.filter((item) => item.size === 'XL'))
    } else {
      return console.log(products)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <label>
        Order:
        <select>
          <option value="lowest">Lowest to Highest</option>
          <option value="highest">Highest to Lowest</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Size:
        <select className="size" onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="">ALL</option>
          <option value="XS">XS</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Filter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning:

```
return (
              console.log(products.filter(item =>item.size === "S"  ) ) 
                 
            )
```

`console.log()` of course has no effect on the actual component state.
Try using `setItem(products)` to update your state

Comment: alright did that, but i think i am doing something wrong with the render.

Comment: is console.log printing anything?

Comment: yes, it console.logs the products based on the selected size

Comment: where do you want the filtered products? If you need to have them filtered in another component such as a products table, then you'll have to use another state for them. As you wrote it, your filtered products will only be available inside the filter component

Answer (score 0):

And this is where i made my product component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { Library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faShoppingBasket } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Filter from './filter'
import { listProduct } from '../../actions/productActions'

function Product(props) {
  //default value is an array, because we've got data in an array
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)

  const { products, loading, error } = productList
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [items, setItems] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProduct())
  }, [])

  // handlefilter

  // handle cart adding
  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    props.history.push('/cart/' + props.match.params.id + '?qty' + qty)
  }

  return (
    // Check the loading before rendering products
    loading ? (
      <div>
        <h1 className="load">loading...</h1>
      </div>
    ) : error ? (
      <div>{error}</div>
    ) : (
      <ul className="products">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.id} className="product">
            <Link to={'/product/' + product.id}>
              <div
                className="img"
                style={{
                  background: `url(${product.img})`,
                  backgroundSize: 'cover',
                }}
              ></div>
            </Link>
            {/* LOOK OUT FOR TYPOS IN ROUTIING  dont put':' after /, this only applies
                       when routing because the ": " implies for a parameter
                       In this case you can directly access product.id  */}
            <Link to={'/product/' + product.id}>
              <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            </Link>
            <p>
              {' '}
              <small>€</small>
              {product.price}
            </p>
            <div>size: {product.size}</div>

            {product.qty > 0 ? (
              <div>
                <button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to cart</button>{' '}
                <div>{product.qty} left</div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>out of stock</div>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  )
}
export default Product
```

so i want to render the specific product based on the selected size

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const products = [
    { size: "S" },
    { size: "S" },
    { size: "XS" },
    { size: "XS" },
    { size: "M" },
    { size: "M" },
    { size: "L" },
    { size: "L" },
    { size: "XL" },
    { size: "XL" }
  ];
  const [items, setItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItem(products);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    let filteredProducts = [];
    filteredProducts =
      value === "ALL"
        ? [...products]
        : products.filter((item) => item.size === value);

    console.log(value);

    setItem(filteredProducts);
  };

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <label>
        Order:
        <select>
          <option value="lowest">Lowest to Highest</option>
          <option value="highest">Highest to Lowest</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Size:
        <select className="size" onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
          <option value="XS">XS</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
        </select>
      </label>

      <ul>
        {items.map((p) => (
          <li>{p.size}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You just need to pass filtered array to setItems and render items in html.